# How to calculate size of java object when designing API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, api, rest, gateway

We are building Rest bulk Api fronted by API Gateway to which can serve data upto 1MiB.  what are some best practices to keep this limit. Should we calculate the size of java object on the fly and throw exception if it exceeds?

Comment: Is that 1 megabit or 1 megabyte?  What happens if the data exceeds the limit?  How are you serving the data?  Any API will return a collection of bytes, which you can count.

Comment: It's 1 mebiByte ~ 1megabyte.  If data exceed the limit, we want to throw an exception

Comment: Fine.  Count the bytes and prepare an alternate message to return to the front end when the API would return a message > 1 megabyte.  Your front end will have to translate this message into something the user can take action with.